# Ages between 18-24, if statement

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and I'm doing all the Java exercises on programmingbydoing. I get errors in my code cause I don't know what "symbol" or structure I'm supposed to be using.

`else if ( age == 18 || 19 || 20 || 21 || 22 || 23 || 24 )
        {
            System.out.println ( "You can vote but not rent a car" + name);
        }`

Comment: (age == 18 || age == 19 || age == 20 || ... )... (or age>=18&&age<=24)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your second suggestion worked as I got some error to do with "boolean/integers" or something like that, on the first one.

Comment: In the future, it's better to ask these kinds of questions in StackOverflow.com

Comment: Ok. Generally what's the difference with this sub?

Comment: StackOverflow is generally for practical coding questions such as this one. Programmers is more for conceptual questions regarding programming. So this question is off topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no easy "is one of" operator in java, if you want that you need to do

```
if(age == 18 || age == 19 || age == 20 || age == 21 || age == 21 || age == 22 || age == 23 || age == 24)
```

but since you have a range where the value needs to be in, you can do

```
if(age >= 18 && age <= 24)
```

Comment: Good to know. Figured that the second one is much easier for wider ranges. Cheers.

Comment: @Rockett: note that if `age` is of type `float` or `double`, the semantics of both statements are not the same, and your original approach might lead to a wrong result (consider what happens when age is 18.5 ). So testing with `>=` is not only a matter of "easiness", its a matter of correctness.

Answer (score 1):

You can also build an `ArrayList` of relevant values, and check if `age` is one of them using `contains`

```
List<Integer> voteButNotRentAges = Arrays.asList(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24);
if (voteButNotRentAges.contains(age)) {
    System.out.println("You can vote but not rent a car" + name);
}
```

Comment: First, you can't use a primitive as a generic type parameter.  Second, this operation is far more inefficient than merely checking a logical AND (since you have to traverse the entire list to check every age you enter in).

Comment: @Makoto - I've fixed the type of the generic parameter. AFAIK - `contains` does _not_ traverse the entire list - it returns on the first object which fits.

Comment: Yup, I like this one better, as it allows easier refactoring if the list of ages changes or can be passed into the function. @Makoto - it doesn't necessarily traverse over the entire list if it is found - if it's not found, it's no worse than the alternative of manually checking every value.

Comment: Its worse case performance is to trawl the entire list.  Yes, I realize that it will exit early if the value is found before the end of the list, but if you're checking the extreme end of the list, then you're going to check every element.  To that end - I don't see why this would be preferable; creating a new object only for the sake of throwing it away later, when the bounds check is more efficient and doesn't create any unnecessary objects.

Comment: @UriAgassi - is there a reason you're creating two lists here: `new ArrayList` and `Arrays.asList`? You should not need to wrap with `new ArrayList`...

Comment: @Makoto Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Simplicity is more important than negligible performance difference. This version is valid alternative to the accepted answer and more suitable to non-continuous ranges of integers or non-integer comparisons (e.g. strings).

Answer (score 1):

make your if statement to

```
if(age >= 18 && age <= 24)
```